# snowflake special character parsing issue searching for solution

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a field name called question and value in that field is **How do you think of ${question_1}?**

I want to write a query to select this value and I think it's going to use regular expression to do it. Below is the query but it didn't get the result, anyone can help me? Thanks!

```
select question
from "<table_name>"
where question regexp '.*\s[${].*\s[}?].*';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression appears incorrect here. Keep in mind that pattern matchers such as `.*` and `.+` [are greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) and will match more character types than you may have intended. Also, the `[${]` and `[}?]` bracket expressions in your regex is indicating match either `$` **or** `{`, and `}` **or** `?` respectively, which is not what you are intending to perform.

If your goal is simply to find all text that conforms to the below form specifically:

```
Does every question end with a question-mark immediately after the ${variable}?
```

Then a fitting pattern for it in Snowflake SQL could be:

```sql
select question
from "<table_name>"
where question regexp '.*\\$\\{[^${}]+\\}\\?$';
```

Notice the [double-backslashing](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp.html#examples) (`\\$`, `\\{`, etc.) to disallow treating `$` and `{` as [regular expression instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) (to treat them as simple characters), and the use of an inverted bracket expression `[^${}]` which will accept anything except the characters `$`, `{`, or `}` once the matcher is searching within a potential variable.

The extra `$` instruction at the end is to filter only for text that always ends in a question-mark, and can be dropped if a question-mark does not terminate the string every time in your data.

You can extend this to match (and/or capture) multiple variables too, if more than one variable can be present:

```sql
select
   question
  ,regexp_substr(question, '(\\$\\{[^${}]+\\})', 1, 1) variable_1
  ,regexp_substr(question, '(\\$\\{[^${}]+\\})', 1, 2) variable_2
from "<table_name>"
where question regexp '.*(\\$\\{[^${}]+\\}).*\\?.*'
```

The above will match also for question strings such as:

```
Does this question ${carry} two ${variables}?
```

I recommend building and understanding your own regular expression pattern [interactively with a list of questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8f3G.png) to test against, on websites like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), [RegExr](https://regexr.com/), etc. that make it easier.